# JS Recursive Function Breaking

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have been using Recursive Functions for quite a while now and I am completely baffled by my current problem. Here is my code:

```
var setbackArray = new Array();
setbackArray = [5, 15, 20];
var positionArray = new Array();
positionArray = ["28.0", "28.0", "24.4", "24.4", "24.4", "28.0", "28.0", "28.0", "28.0", "28.0", "24.4", "28.0", "28.0", "28.0", "24.4", "24.4", "24.4", "24.4", "24.4", "24.4", "24.4", "24.4", "24.4", "24.4", "18.5", "18.5", "18.5", "18.5", "22.1", "22.1", "22.1", "22.1", "28.0", "28.0", "28.0", "28.0", "38.6", "38.6", "32.7", "32.7", "38.6", "32.7", "38.6", "32.7", "32.7", "38.6", "38.6", "38.6", "32.7", "32.7", "32.7", "38.6", "32.7", "38.6", "32.7", "38.6", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "43.2", "22.1", "22.1", "22.1", "22.1", "22.1", "22.1", "22.1", "22.1", "22.1", "22.1", "32.7", "32.7", "32.7", "32.7", "38.6", "38.6", "38.6", "38.6"]
var recursive = function (i, length) {
    console.log('i: ' + i + ', length: ' + length);
    if (i < length) {
        var seatposition = Number(positionArray[i]).toFixed(1);
        console.log(seatposition);
        if (seatposition < setbackArray[setbackArray.length - 1] + 20 && seatposition > setbackArray[0] - 20) {
            console.log('Doing Some Math.....');
        } else {
            console.log('Not Usable');
            recursive(++i, length);
        }
        console.log('Doing More Math.......');
        console.log('Doing Even More Math.......');
        console.log('Doing Last Bit Of Math.......');
        console.log('Display Stuff On Screen');
        recursive(++i, length);
    } else {
        console.log('done checking');
    }
}
recursive(0, positionArray.length);
```

In the actual code, both arrays are created dynamically, I just coded them here so that you have a realistic sample. Basically I am going through all of the numbers in the positionArray and seeing if the number is less than the highest number in the setbackArray plus 20 and greater than the smallest number in the setbackArray minus 20. If it is I do some math with it to be used later. If it isn't I want it to move on to the next number in the positionArray.

The problem I am running into is that once i < length is no longer true, it shows "done checking" and then resets i to a previous value and continues to run. It does this without end and crashes the whole page.

I know that the issue lies right here:

```
} else {
      console.log('Not Usable');
      recursive(++i, length);
}
```

If I remove the recursive callout, it runs normally but performs the additional math that I don't want to perform on that number.

Any ideas?

Working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ckxo6x4j/37/)

Comment: Try `recursive(i+1, length);` instead - you seem to need `i` again?

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but why would you initialize `setbackArray` to `new Array();` when you're just going to do `setbackArray = [5, 15, 20]` on the next line? `var setbackArray = [5, 15, 20];` is all you need.

Comment: BTW, why do you have `recursive(++i, length);` on two separate lines? I think one of them doesn't belong there.

Comment: If the validation against the setbackArray fails, I want it to move on to the next number. If is succeeds, I want it to do some more work and then move on to the next number. Hence the two separate calls to continue on to the next number.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this line either: `var seatposition = Number(positionArray[i]).toFixed(1);` That converts the numeric string at `positionArray[i]` to a number, then back to a string. Everything you have in `positionArray` should come out of that unchanged. I'm not really sure why they're strings in the first place, since you're just comparing them to numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your input Justin, but please stick to the question at hand. 

I did that step so that I don't have to write Number(positionArray[i]).toFixed(1) over and over again. I am converting it to a number because it comes from a database that has it as a string. I am using .toFixed(1) because I only want it to one decimal place instead of the 4 decimal places in the database.

Comment: That makes a bit more sense. Looks like es128 covered it, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that what you intended in the problematic `else` block you identified is actually:

```
    } else {
        console.log('Not Usable');
        return recursive(++i, length);
    }
```

which would short-circuit the rest of the function for a "not usable" value.

As it is now, you're recursively calling your function twice in that scenario, leading to a forked control-flow as the recursion continues down multiple paths.

Another way to refactor and fix that section would be:

```
    var seatposition = Number(positionArray[i]).toFixed(1);
    console.log(seatposition);
    if (seatposition < setbackArray[setbackArray.length - 1] + 20 && seatposition > setbackArray[0] - 20) {
        console.log('Doing Some Math.....');
        console.log('Doing More Math.......');
        console.log('Doing Even More Math.......');
        console.log('Doing Last Bit Of Math.......');
        console.log('Display Stuff On Screen');
    } else {
        console.log('Not Usable');
    }
    recursive(++i, length);
```

Comment: That is what appears to be happening, but how would I fix it? I want it to skip the rest of the remaining steps and continue the recursive on the next number.

Comment: I've provided two suggestions. The one that requires the least rearranging of code is to add a `return` statement in that `else` block.

Comment: That is what I needed, the "return" Thank you!!